# Как передать большой массив байтов используя Socket(UDP)

Tags: c#, сокет, udp

Я знаю что существует UdpClient но таковы условия, использовать Socket.

У меня 2 приложения, FPW который отправляет на сервер запрос сделать скриншот и показать этот скриншот, и консольное приложение-сервер который получает команду и делает скриншот.

Код WPF (рабочий)

```
var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            EndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 27001);


            byte[] img = new byte[ushort.MaxValue];
            client.SendTo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("screen"), endPoint);

            var imgByte = client.ReceiveFrom(img, ref endPoint);
            var recMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(img, 0, imgByte);
```

Здесь происходит отправка команды screen чтобы сервер сделал скриншот

код консольного приложения

```
var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            var listenerEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 27001);
            EndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            listener.Bind(listenerEP);

            var buffer = new byte[ushort.MaxValue];

            Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
            Size size = new Size(bit.Width, bit.Height);
            Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bit);
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();

 while (true)
            {
                var len = listener.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref endPoint);

                // if получает команду screen и входит в кот для скриншота
                if (Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, len) == "screen")
                {
                    //здесь получается скриншот и переводится в массив байтов для дальнейший отправки в приложение WPF
                    graphic.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, size);
                    byte[] imgByte = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bit, typeof(byte[]));

                    // отправка байтов (выдаёт ошибку потому что массив слишком велик
                    listener.SendTo(imgByte, 0,  endPoint);


                }
```

и вот тут на отправке я не могу придумать как правильнее отправить этот массив
Перед отправкой массива imgByte я проверял отправку другим более мелким массивом и всё работало, то есть отправка есть но как правильно мне отправить код я не знаю
Если есть знающие прошу подскажите, буду благодарен. И повторюсь, условия домашнего задания таковы что надо использовать Socket и отправлять по UDP протоколу.

Мне просто надо узнать как правильно отправить массив а дальше я уже знаю как байты перевести обратно в фотографию и показать в приложении.

Comment: UDP может терять пакеты, потребуется контроль и повторная пересылка. Для передачи файлов лучше использовать TCP. UDP больше подходит для потокового вещания, где допустимы потери и не требуется повторная отправка.

Comment: `Socket` напрямую использовать мало смысла, используйте `UdpListener` и `UdpClient`. Меньше сложого обвязочного кода писать придется.

Comment: Разбейте массив на много маленьких, скажем по 16 кило, отправьте приемнику управляющий пакет с длиной файла. Пронумеруйте все пакеты в заголовках перед данными. Учтите что приемник может получать пакеты не в том порядке, в котором они были отправлены. Научите его перезапрашивать утеряные или неполностью доставленные фрагменты.

Comment: Ну вот я тоже думаю как его разбить и отправить но не знаю как правильно

Comment: Сначала сделайте хоть как-нибудь, а потом думайте, как правильнее.

Comment: По UDP - будет больно, почему именно UDP? Для передачи таких вещей, обычно, используют TCP

Comment: Я понимаю что TCP будет лучше, но в домашнем задании таковы требования "Использовать Socket UDP". Я знаю разницу между TCP и UDP